# Meta Tags not shown in Search Engine

Tags: seo, meta-tags, meta

I've added complete tags in the home page. But When I tried to find website on search engine it shows brand name only.

Meta Description is appearing correctly in search engine but instead of showing Meta title it shows Brand name.

Please share your feedback so that I can add accurately.

Comment: Search engines may not care about your meta tags.  Some people think they are almost useless for SEO http://cohlab.com/blog/stop-using-keywords-meta-tag.html

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, But technology changes everyday specially google algorithms and you shared January 5, 2014 article. Which I think I should stop this to share anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Meta tags are important part of SEO, but not the primary factors.
When you say they do not show, i believe you are talking specific tags, such as keyword tag, in such case please not that keyword tag is not anymore a factor in SEO for search engines such as Google, for Meta Title, your page title will show first that is also because the meta title has also been deprecated.

Use your meta tags for description and social graph, that's the most you will need in meta for SEO.